# Mapbox-gl offline openmaptile font not shown

Tags: labeling, tiles, mapbox-gl-js, font, openmaptiles

I'be downloaded a mbtile file related to rtl countries and used it as an offline source for Mapbox-gl server.

All stuff are shown correctly except labels that have rtl characters. Even ltr characters are shown in correct format.

Can anyone give some solution to this problem or even some technical clues?